# "to do something and do something" vs "to do something and to do something" (what to use after the coordinate conjunction "and")

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

> 1 I seek knowledge about the brain in order to satisfy my curiosity regarding this amazing organ that has brought us intelligence and develop more intelligent  systems that provide benefits for humanity.

> 2 I seek knowledge about the brain in order to satisfy my curiosity regarding this amazing organ that has brought us intelligence and **to** develop more intelligent  systems that provide benefits for humanity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second is correct. Because they are long sentences, the first version is confusing. You need to include *to* to alert the reader that what follows is another of your intentions rather than something else that the brain does.

In a shorter sentence this isn't necessary - as in the famous book title "How to win friends and influence people".